# Delete first words from all folder names in directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, rename

Anyone knows how to write a bash script that can rename all folders in a directory? It needs to delete the first words of all folders.

Currently it looks like this:

```
ABC DEF Folder1
ABC DEF Folder2
ABC DEF Folder3
...
ABC DEF Folder1000
```

Delete the identical letters

> ABC DEF

To achieve

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
...
Folder1000
```

I'm kinda new to linux and don't got a clue about bash scripting yet. Anyone who can provide hints/ solutions?

[A real live preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGVKR.png)

Comment: why use a script?   why not just `rename`  (with globbing)

Comment: Because that's a shit tons of work for a huge amount of folders and I know a smarter solution is possible. I want to save some of the chars to be able to identify the folders by their name.

Comment: `rename s/ABC\ DEF\ //  *`  isn't a lot a work

Comment: `krename` is a useful gui tool here, particularly if you have KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Answer

I'd not bother with script ... just `rename`

`rename s/ABC\ DEF\ // *`

s/string1/string2/
causes it to search & replace string1 with string 2.

string 1 is made longer due spaces and need to escape them '\ ', string 2 being empty '//'

finally * forces it to work on all files/dirs in current directory

Read the `man rename` and it'll provide clues. The main page refererences ' perlexprs' (perl expressions; meaning more `man` pages) but they are a superset of POSIX ones meaning you have more power, but can just limit yourself to posix too.

Answer (score 2):

For simple text matches such as this (which don't really require the power of regular expressions) there's also `mmv` e.g. given

```
$ ls -d */
ABC DEF Folder1/   ABC DEF Folder3/  ABC DEF Folder6/  ABC DEF Folder9/
ABC DEF Folder10/  ABC DEF Folder4/  ABC DEF Folder7/
ABC DEF Folder2/   ABC DEF Folder5/  ABC DEF Folder8/
```

then

```
mmv -r 'ABC DEF *' '#1'
```

results in

```
$ ls -d */
Folder1/   Folder2/  Folder4/  Folder6/  Folder8/
Folder10/  Folder3/  Folder5/  Folder7/  Folder9/
```

---

FWIW it's not actually much more work to script it in the (bash, or POSIX sh) shell -

```
for f in */; do mv -- "$f" "${f#ABC DEF }"; done
```